# Issues while using Open Frameworks CvCameraProjectorCalibration example

Tags: opencv, frameworks, camera, calibration, projector

I'm currently developing a projection mapping application within Unity3D and I've reached a point where I require projector's intrisic/extrinsic matrix. In order to obtain them, I'm trying out the [ofxCvCameraProjectorCalibration](https://github.com/kikko/ofxCvCameraProjectorCalibration) addon (using the calibration example available in the pack) and been having some issues:

1) The application is divided in 3 states: CAMERA, PROJECTOR_STATIC and PROJECTOR_DYNAMIC. In each state the corresponding device is calibrated. A video of demonstrating the process using a similar application can be seen[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCq7u2TvlxU). Upon reaching the final state (the dynamic one), the dots used in the projector calibration that were originally being projected in the Static state are almost gone - and I say almost because sometimes 1-4 dots show up on random locations unlike on the video I mentioned before. Since the calibration process comes to a halt, the application doesn't get to the point in the code where both CameraProjectorExtrinsics.yml and calibrationProjector.yml are generated!

2) The clean(maxReprojErrorCamera) crashes the application. In order to fully run the application, I have to set a high value in settings.xml so that this function is never called, however from what I've understood this function isn't mandatory but how much impact does it have on the calibration?

3) Are the values obtained in the extrinsic matrix of the projector measurable in meters or cm?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!